# How to double the DC voltage during start-up

Tags: voltage, mosfet, dc, voltage-doubler

Is there any simple way to double the DC voltage during the first 10-50 ms? For example - I need 6V at startup and then go back to 3V that is set on power supply.
My current solution is Attiny85 and logic-level MOSFET with power supply that is set on 6V and then 3V is obtained with PWM regulation on MOSFET. This solution is working, but I think that is a bit overkill to put MCU for such a simple task but also I can't figure out smaller and simpler solution.

Edit: Load is DC motor that is designed to work in 3-6V range. When motor is started it draws arround 500 mA. But in order to start this motor with load coupled to the motor I need at least 6-7V. I've tried before to put capacitor of 10000uF before NPN transistor that is used as switch for the motor and switch the transistor with really fast Schmitt trigger but that doesn't work.

Comment: It might be nice to see your current solution. This would say a great deal about your current situation that you have, for some reason, decided not to write about. So a diagram may save everyone some time asking questions.

Comment: Voltage increases are tougher than decreases so you're not on a bad track.  pwm control seems iffy for something that a switching vreg could do.  If current is low enough you could charge a cap and use that initially.  vreg of appropriate spec (or diode protection) would only kick in after cap discharged below 3V and the cap would continue to serve as part of regulated 3V.

Comment: How much current does the load draw at 6V and at 3V? How fast does the voltage have to drop back to 3V? What kind of load is it?

Comment: We need more details about the application. There are some clever tricks you can use to get this type of effect, but it depends on the load and supply.

Comment: That's an unusual requirement. Perhaps you could explain the reason you want to do this. There might be other options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of most trivial method is to use a follower like this. You will probably have to modify it according your needs, but the principle:

When switch is off the capacitor is discharged to 0V. After switch is on the discharged capacitor pulls the base almost to Vcc what sets the motor voltage to Vcc-0.7v

Then the capacitor is continously charged so the motor voltage is decresing.
The final motor voltage (after this initial transition) is set with R1,R2 devider minus 0.7v on Vbe.

The transition time can be changed with C1.

[image]

Motor voltage:
[image: Motor voltage]

If you want to switch the motor with some Control Signal use this:

After Control signal come the C1 starts charging and after 20ms Q2 switches the motor voltage from Vcc-0.7 to voltage given by R2,R3 devider (-0.7v on Vbe of Q1). M1 disconnects the motor when control signal is low.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This solution is brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want PWM control of the motor.  Use an H-bridge or transistor with a 6-volt supply, start it up with a 100% duty cycle, and then cut back to a 50% duty cycle.